# WooCommerce: Adding Order Item Meta Data That's Hidden

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, metadata

I was under the impression that if you add an underscore to your meta_key, it would be hidden from the Admin and subsequently the Order Receipts, etc.

But, mine are showing? I don't understand what's going on...

meta_key: `_testing_this`, meta_value: `asdasdasd`

How do I added order item meta without it showing up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to serialize the data you want to be hidden.

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding correctly, to hide order metadata, you could use the existing hook [Hidden Order Item Meta](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta/).

You could possibly add this to your functions.php or wherever you are storing your customizations:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta', 'add_your_hidden_order_items' );
function add_your_hidden_order_items( $order_items ) {
    $order_items[] = '_testing_this';
    // any other entries you want to hide..
    return $order_items;
}
```

I'm not sure this will remove the meta from the admin view. It may be worth while looking at [this post about customizing the order meta box](https://blackandwhiteshades.wordpress.com/2015/07/31/customize-woocommerce-admin-order-item-meta/).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly how to add meta data to an order. The issue is that I need to add some meta data to the order that is not automatically processed within the order emails and admin order information views.